# How to append a text in a Xml DOCTYPE declaration reference?

Tags: c#, xml, append, doctype

Lets say I've a doctype :

```
<!DOCTYPE beer PUBLIC "-//BEER//DTD beer DTD version 2.0//KF//XML" "Kingfisher.dtd">
```

My requirement is I have a path(text) which needs to be appended to the doctype like this :

```
path = "C:/Beer/"
```

So after appending path to dtd reference, my doctype should look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE beer PUBLIC "-//BEER//DTD beer DTD version 2.0//KF//XML" "C:/Beer/Kingfisher.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could do this with regex, but you shouldn't. There are much better xml manipulation tools in .net.

```
var xml = "<!DOCTYPE beer PUBLIC \"-//BEER//DTD beer DTD version 2.0//KF//XML\" \"Kingfisher.dtd\"><root></root>";

var xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var path = "C:/Beer/";
xd.DocumentType.SystemId = Path.Combine(path, xd.DocumentType.SystemId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><!DOCTYPE beer PUBLIC \"-//BEER//DTD beer DTD version 2.0//KF//XML\" \"Kingfisher.dtd\"><root></root>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XDocumentType _type  =  (XDocumentType)doc.Nodes().Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.DocumentType).FirstOrDefault();
            _type.SystemId = "C:/Beer/Kingfisher.dtd";

        }
    }
}
```